# Не устанавливается laravel/breeze

Tags: laravel

При установке командой `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` выдает ошибки:

```
- laravel/breeze[v1.4.0, ..., v1.4.1] require illuminate/support ^8.42 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.42.0, ..., v8.60.0].
- illuminate/support[v8.42.0, ..., v8.60.0] require ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].
```

Как решить проблему? Подскажите!

Comment: Там же написано `ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.`, -- следственно Вам нужно установить или включить расширение `mbstring`

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в php.ini
Там найдите строчку

> extension=mbstring

если спереду стоит ";" - уберите этот знак, чтобы строка выглядела так как я показал. Это знак комментария
Так же убедитесь что у вас есть файл по пути:

> php-директория/ext/php_mbstring.dll

Если нет такого - нужно доставить.
После этого - попробуйте установить

Если после всего не заработает - напишите мне